# How to replace string within TCP payload (PyDivert)

Tags: python, tcp

I've been using PyDivert to receive packets, and I've been wanting to use it to alter outgoing packet's payloads. I am using TCP. Here's an example of the type of data I receive as a payload:

```
[Byte] b't\x00\x00\x00\x94\x0c\x80\x00\nj"h\n\x0517332\x12\x073138409\x1aN\n\nPlayerUserName\x12\rGlobalName*\x06\n\x02hi\x12\x00'
```

And here's an example of the code I've used to get the payload, and alter it:

```
import pydivert
w = pydivert.WinDivert("tcp.DstPort == 20206 and tcp.PayloadLength > 0")
w.open()
packet = w.recv()
payload = packet.payload

newPayload = payload.decode()
newPayload.replace("OldString","NewString")

packet.payload = newPayload.encode()

###################
packet.recalculate_checksums(0)
w.send(packet,recalculate_checksum=True)
w.close()
```

A problem I have been having is changing the strings within the payload. I have found success in decoding the payload using UTF-8 schemes but it doesn't work for all of the network traffic I've encountered with this program. I've also gone ahead and tried CharDetect on python to see if I could try some other codec to resolve the issue, but to no avail.

However, I've found SOME success with some packets that have been UTF-8 decoded, and have been able to replace some data if the payload sizes are the same.

Would there be some other way that I could replace a string within the payload data, or some way to decode the codec the payload is using?

Comment: Blind `.decode()` (default UTF-8) of a binary packet makes no sense.  Your example packet, for example, is clearly not UTF-8-encoded.  Note that you *can* use `.replace()` with byte strings, e.g., `newPayload = newPayload.replace(b"OldString", b"NewString")`.  No need to decode.